# *args and methods that expect a specific number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

instead of this

```
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module FormHelper
      def text_area_with_wrap(object_name, method, options)
        "<span class=\"wrap\">#{text_area_without_wrap(object_name, method, options)}</span>"
      end
      alias_method_chain :text_area, :wrap
    end
  end
end
```

for obvious reasons I would want to do this

```
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module FormHelper
      def text_area_with_wrap(*args)
        "<span class=\"wrap\">#{text_area_without_wrap(args)}</span>"
      end
      alias_method_chain :text_area, :wrap
    end
  end
end
```

Does any of you know if and how this can be done? Can't find it in the manuals.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: can't read out the obvious reasons for that.

It breaks structure validity for having block element (textarea) inside inline element(span)

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work:

```
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module FormHelper
      def text_area_with_wrap(*args)
        "<span class=\"wrap\">#{text_area_without_wrap(*args)}</span>"
      end
      alias_method_chain :text_area, :wrap
    end
  end
end
```

Note the extra `*`.

Comment: As I understand it, `*args` in a method definition sucks all the remaining parameters into a single array, and `*args` elsewhere expands a single array into all its elements.

Comment: Exactly. `*args` is always the last parameter of a given method and consumes all the remaining arguments.